# Display table properly using tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I have an order tracking system with collapsible containers which contains tabs with a different table. However, whenever the user clicks the second order number and chooses a tab, the table will not show where it supposed to be but shows on the first order number table. For example, I chose order number 67890 and tabbed it to logistics, it should show the logistics table on the 67890 rows but it remained static and showed the table on the first row which is order number 12345.

How can I show the table with correspond to the chosen order number and tab? Please help

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('.closedArrow').click(function() {
         $(this).parents('tr').children('.expanded').toggle();
         $(this).parents('tr').children('.collapsed').toggle();
         $(this).toggleClass( "openArrow" );    
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function addRow(){
 var table = document.getElementById("Section3_table");
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
 
 
 row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="issue[]" required/>';
 row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="details[]" size="20" required/>';
 row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="Delete" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)"/>';
} 

function deleteRow(obj) {
     
    var index = obj.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var table = document.getElementById("Section3_table");
    table.deleteRow(index);
   
}
```

```css
.closedArrow {
 <!-- background: url('http://is200.imagesocket.com/images/2014/10/29/2716484-3exx.png') no-repeat 1px 1px; --> 
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-top: 4px; 
 cursor:pointer;
}

.openArrow {
 <!-- background: url('http://is200.imagesocket.com/images/2014/10/29/2716483-0cvp.png') no-repeat 1px 1px; -->
 padding-left: 20px;
 cursor:pointer;
}

.steps {
    margin:0 0 20px;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.green {
 background:#7dba00 !important; 
 color: #666666 !important;
}

.grey {
 color: #666666 !important;
}

.open .green:after  {
 border-left-color: #7dba00 !important;
}

.wrap .num.last:after {
 display:none
}
.wrap .num.last:before {
 display:none
}

.black {
 background:#000 !important; 
 color:#fff!important;
}

.open .black:after  {
 border-left-color: #000 !important; 
 color:#fff!important;
}

.steps li {
 float:left;
 position:relative;
}

.wrap {
 float:left;
}

.num {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background:#7dba00;
    color:#000;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 4px 0 0;
}

.num b, .steps p span {
 position:relative;
 z-index:2; 
 display:block;
}

.num:after {
    content:" ";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 14px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 14px solid #fff;
    border-left: 14px solid #7dba00;
    position:absolute;
    right:-4px;
    top:1px;
}

.steps p {
    background: #fff;
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 14px;
 font-size: 10px;
 width: 10em;
 padding: 0 10px 0 0px;
 text-align: center;
}


.closed .num:after {
 border-left-color:#000
}

.closed .num {
 color:#fff;
 background:#000
}

.closed .num.last:after {
 display:none
}

.open .num:after {
    border-left-color:#ccc;
    border-top-color:transparent;
    border-bottom-color:transparent;
    z-index:1;
}

.open .num:before {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    content:" ";
    position:absolute;
    border-top: 15px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 15px solid #fff;
    border-left: 15px solid #7dba00;
    position:absolute;
    right:-5px;
    top:0;
    z-index:0;
}

.open .num {
 background:#ccc;
}

.open .wrap {
 border-radius:15px 0 0 15px;
 border:1px solid #7dba00;
}

li.open:after {
    content:" ";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 16px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 16px solid #fff;
    border-left: 15px solid #7dba00;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:0;
}

li.open:before {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    content:" ";
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
    border-left: 14px solid #fff;
    position:absolute;
    right:1px;
    top:1px;
    z-index:1;
}

.expanded {
 display:none;
 <!--bbackground-color: red;-->
 padding-right: 900px;
}

.tab {
 <!--background-color: yellow; -->
 <!--border: 2px solid black; -->
 border-collapse: collapse;
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 15px;
 text-align: left;
 width: 85%;
 margin-left: 230px;
}

.column {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}

.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .column {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
 
  
.completed span {
    background-color:NONE;
    color:#95db89;
    border:2px solid #95db89;
}

.todo span {
    background-color:none;
    color:#E1E6EB;
    border:2px solid #E1E6EB;
}
  
.list span {
 color:#58D68D;
 font-weight:500;
 font-size: 12px;
}
    
.breadcrumb-pagination div p {
    text-align:center;
    line-height:0;
    margin:30px auto 25px;
 }
    
.active p {
   border-bottom:2px solid #00abc9;
   padding-bottom:27px;
   margin-bottom:0px !important;
   color: #3c4043;
   font-weight:700;  
}

    
.completed p {
    color:#bsb7c1;
  }
 
.list p {
    color:#3c4043;
 font-weight:700;
  }

.completed span::before { 
  content: '\2713' 
}

.title{
 text-align:center;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-left: 365px;
 color: #444;
}

table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff; 
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 15px;
 text-align: left;
 width: 98%;
} 

th {
 background: linear-gradient(#000000, #4d4d4d);
 border-left: 1px solid #555;
 border-right: 1px solid #777;
 border-top: 1px solid #555;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #999;
 color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 position: relative;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000; 
}

th:after {
 background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,.08));
 content: '';
 display: block;
 height: 15%;
 left: 0;
 margin: 1px 0 0 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 25%;
 width: 100%;
}

th:first-child {
 border-left: 1px solid #777; 
 box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 #999;
}

th:last-child {
 box-shadow: inset -1px 1px 0 #999;
}

td {
 border-right: 1px solid #fff;
 border-left: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
 border-top: 1px solid #fff;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
 padding: 8px ;
 position: relative;
 transition: all 300ms;
}

td:first-child {
 box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 #fff;
} 

td:last-child {
 border-right: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
 box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 #fff;
} 

tr {
 background: url(https://jackrugile.com/images/misc/noise-diagonal.png); 
}

tr:nth-child(odd) td {
 background: #f1f1f1 url(https://jackrugile.com/images/misc/noise-diagonal.png); 
}

tr:last-of-type td {
 box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 #fff; 
}

tr:last-of-type td:first-child {
 box-shadow: inset 1px -1px 0 #fff;
} 

tr:last-of-type td:last-child {
 box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 0 #fff;
}

h1 {
 color: #444;
 text-shadow: 
    1px 0px 1px #ccc, 0px 1px 1px #eee, 
    2px 1px 1px #ccc, 1px 2px 1px #eee,
    3px 2px 1px #ccc, 2px 3px 1px #eee,
    4px 3px 1px #ccc, 3px 4px 1px #eee,
    5px 4px 1px #ccc, 4px 5px 1px #eee,
    6px 5px 1px #ccc, 5px 6px 1px #eee,
    7px 6px 1px #ccc;
}

a:hover,a:focus{
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.tab { 
 text-align: center; 
}

.tab .nav-tabs{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: none;
}

.tab .nav-tabs li{
    margin: 0;
}

.tab .nav-tabs li a{
    display: block;
    padding: 80px 25px 0 25px;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    margin-right: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.tab .nav-tabs li a span {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #999;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.tab .nav-tabs li.active a span{
    background: #29335c;
    color: #fff;
}

.tab .nav-tabs li a span i{
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.tab .nav-tabs li.active a,
.tab .nav-tabs li a:hover{
    color: black;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

.tab .nav-tabs li.active a{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #29335c;
}

.tab .tab-content{
    padding: 30px 0 0 19px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: black;
    line-height: 26px;
    text-align: left;
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
 width: 600px;
}

.tab .tab-content .tab-pane #Section3_table {
 margin-left: -8px;
}

.tab .tab-content h3{
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px){
    .tab .nav-tabs li{
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    .tab .nav-tabs li:last-child{
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons\">  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>

<body>
<title> Order Tracking System </title>
<center>
<h1> ORDER TRACKING SYSTEM </h1>
<br>
<table class="bts_table">
  <tr>
    <th>ORDER NUMBER</th>
 <th>CUSTOMER NAME</th>
    <th>LOCATION</th> 
  </tr>

<form action="save.php" method="POST">
    <td valign="top"><span class="closedArrow"> 12345 </span></td>
 <td valign="top"><span class="closedArrow"> JOHN </span></td>
    <td valign="top" class="collapsed"><ol class="steps">
        <li>
                <div class="num green"><b>1</b></div>
        </li>
        <li>
                <div class="num green"><b>2</b></div>
        </li>
  <li>
                <div class="num green"><b>3</b></div>
        </li>
  <li>
                <div class="num green"><b>4</b></div>
        </li>
        <li class="open">
                <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="num grey"><b>5</b></div>
                        <p><span>SHIPPING</span><span>IN PROGRESS</span></p>
                </div>
        </li>
  <li class="closed">
                <div class="num"><b>6</b></div>
        </li>
  <li class="closed">
                <div class="num"><b>7</b></div>
        </li>
  <li class="closed">
                <div class="num"><b>8</b></div>
        </li>
  <li class="closed">
                <div class="num"><b>9</b></div>
        </li>
        <li class="closed">
                <div class="num last"><b>10</b></div>
        </li>

</ol></td>
   <td colspan="2" class="expanded">
  <ol class="steps">
        <li class="open">
                <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="num green"><b>1</b></div>
                        <p><span>ORDER</span><span>Done: 03/18/2019</span></p>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li class="open">
                <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="num green"><b>2</b></div>
                        <p><span>PACKING</span><span>Done: 03/18/2019</span></p>
                </div>
        </li>
  <li class="open">
                <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="num green"><b>3</b></div>
                        <p><span>CHECKING</span><span>Done: 03/18/2019</span></p>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li class="open">
                <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="num green"><b>4</b></div>
                        <p><span>RECHECKING</span><span>Done: 03/18/2019</span></p>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li class="open">
                <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="num grey"><b>5</b></div>
                        <p><span>SHIPPING</span><span>ONGOING</span></p>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li class="open">
                <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="num black"><b>6</b></div>
                        <p><span>COURIER</span><span>NOT YET DONE </span></p>
                </div>
        </li>
  <li class="open">
                <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="num black"><b>7</b></div>
                        <p><span>DELIVERY</span><span>NOT YET DONE </span></p>
                </div>
        
        <li class="open">
                <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="num black last"><b>10</b></div>
                        <p><span>CUSTOMER</span><span>NOT YET DONE </span></p>
                </div>
        </li>
</ol><hr>
<div class="tableDiv">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="tab" role="tabpanel">
                <center>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" style="width: 800px">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#Section1" aria-controls="build_details" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span><i class="fa fa-cog" style="font-size:35px; padding: 8px 9px 9px 11px;"></i></span> Order Details</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#Section2" aria-controls="logistics" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span><i class="fa fa-bar-chart" style="font-size:25px; padding: 12px 9px 9px 10px;"></i></span> Logistics</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#Section3" aria-controls="reports" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span><i class="fa fa-file-text" style="font-size:26px; padding: 14px 9px 9px 13px;"></i></span> Reports</a></li>
     <li role="presentation"><a href="#Section4" aria-controls="shipments" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" style="font-size:34px; padding: 10px 9px 9px 11px;"></i></span> Shipments</a></li>
                </ul>
                
    
                <div class="tab-content tabs">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="Section1">
                        <table border="2px">
       <tr><th>ITEM</th><th>DETAILS</th></tr>
       <tr><td>Bag</td><td>1pc; Green</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Pouch</td><td>1pc; Blue</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Necklace</td><td>1pc; Heart shape; Gold</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Shoes</td><td>1 pair; Red; Size 6</td></tr>
      </table><br><hr>
                    </div>
     
     
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="Section2">
                        <table border="2px">
       <tr><th>CUSTOMER</th></th><th>DETAILS</th></tr>
       <tr><td>NAME</td><td>John Smith</td></tr>
       <tr><td>SHIPPING ADDRESS</td><td> 445 Mount Eden Road, Mount Eden, Auckland. Rural </td></tr>
       <tr><td>TELEPHONE NUMBER</td><td>754-3010</td></tr>
      </table>
                    </div>
     
     
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="Section3">
     <center><a class="btn btn-danger" href="add_report.php">ADD REPORT</a><br><br>
     <table id="Section3_table" name="Section3">
     <tr><th>ISSUE</th><th>DETAILS</th></tr> 
       <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
     </center></table><br><hr>
                    </div>
     
     
     <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="Section4">
                        <table border="2px">
       <tr><th>COURIER NAME</th><th>DATE SHIPPED</th><th>DATE ARRIVED</th></tr>
       <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
      </table><br><hr>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><span class="closedArrow"> 67890 </span></td>
 <td valign="top"><span class="closedArrow"> JANE </span></td>
    <td valign="top" class="collapsed"><ol class="steps">
        <li class="open">
                <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="num grey"><b>1</b></div>
                        <p><span>PACKING</span><span>IN PROGRESS</span></p>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li class="closed">
                <div class="num"><b>2</b></div>
        </li>
  <li class="closed">
                <div class="num"><b>3</b></div>
        </li>
  <li class="closed">
                <div class="num"><b>4</b></div>
        </li>
        <li class="closed">
                <div class="num"><b>5</b></div>
        </li>
  <li class="closed">
                <div class="num"><b>6</b></div>
        </li>
  <li class="closed">
                <div class="num"><b>7</b></div>
        </li>
  <li class="closed">
                <div class="num"><b>8</b></div>
        </li>
  <li class="closed">
                <div class="num"><b>9</b></div>
        </li>
        <li class="closed">
                <div class="num last"><b>10</b></div>
        </li>

</ol></td>
   <td colspan="2" class="expanded">
  <ol class="steps">
        <li class="open">
                <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="num green"><b>1</b></div>
                        <p><span>ORDER</span><span>ONGOING</span></p>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li class="open">
                <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="num black"><b>2</b></div>
                        <p><span>PACKING</span><span>NOT YET DONE</span></p>
                </div>
        </li>
  <li class="open">
                <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="num black"><b>3</b></div>
                        <p><span>CHECKING</span><span>NOT YET DONE</span></p>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li class="open">
                <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="num black"><b>4</b></div>
                        <p><span>RECHECKING</span><span>NOT YET DONE</span></p>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li class="open">
                <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="num black"><b>5</b></div>
                        <p><span>SHIPPING</span><span>NOT YET DONE</span></p>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li class="open">
                <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="num black"><b>6</b></div>
                        <p><span>COURIER</span><span>NOT YET DONE</span></p>
                </div>
        </li>
  <li class="open">
                <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="num black"><b>7</b></div>
                        <p><span>DELIVERY</span><span>NOT YET DONE</span></p>
                </div>
        
        <li class="open">
                <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="num black last"><b>10</b></div>
                        <p><span>CUSTOMER</span><span>NOT YET DONE</span></p>
                </div>
        </li>
</ol><hr>


<div class="tableDiv">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="tab" role="tabpanel">
                <center>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" style="width: 800px">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#Section1" aria-controls="build_details" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span><i class="fa fa-cog" style="font-size:35px; padding: 8px 9px 9px 11px;"></i></span> Order Details</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#Section2" aria-controls="logistics" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span><i class="fa fa-bar-chart" style="font-size:25px; padding: 12px 9px 9px 10px;"></i></span> Logistics</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#Section3" aria-controls="reports" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span><i class="fa fa-file-text" style="font-size:26px; padding: 14px 9px 9px 13px;"></i></span> Reports</a></li>
     <li role="presentation"><a href="#Section4" aria-controls="shipments" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" style="font-size:34px; padding: 10px 9px 9px 11px;"></i></span> Shipments</a></li>
                </ul>
                
    
                <div class="tab-content tabs">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="Section1">
                        <table border="2px">
       <tr><th>ITEM</th><th>DETAILS</th></tr>
       <tr><td>Dress</td><td>1pc; Yellow</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Hat</td><td>1pc; Green</td></tr>
      </table><br><hr>
                    </div>
     
     
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="Section2">
                        <table border="2px">
       <tr><th>CUSTOMER</th></th><th>DETAILS</th></tr>
       <tr><td>NAME</td><td>Jane Doe</td></tr>
       <tr><td>SHIPPING ADDRESS</td><td>21 Greens Road RD 2 Ruawai 0592. Partial addresses: Main Highway </td></tr>
       <tr><td>TELEPHONE NUMBER</td><td>1-541-754-3010</td></tr>
      </table>
                    </div>
     
     
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="Section3">
     <center><a class="btn btn-danger" href="add_report.php">ADD REPORT</a><br><br>
     <table id="Section3_table" name="Section3">
     <tr><th>ISSUE</th><th>DETAILS</th></tr> 
       <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
     </center></table><br><hr>
                    </div>
     
     
     <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="Section4">
                        <table border="2px">
       <tr><th>COURIER NAME</th><th>DATE SHIPPED</th><th>DATE ARRIVED</th></tr>
       <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
      </table><br><hr>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem comes from the duplicate id's, `#Section1,#Section2,#Section3,#Section4` I have changed them in the second row to `#Section5,#Section6,#Section7,#Section8` and you could see that it works.

**NOTE:** The id must be unique in the same document.

```css
.closedArrow {
  <!-- background: url('http://is200.imagesocket.com/images/2014/10/29/2716484-3exx.png') no-repeat 1px 1px;
  -->padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.openArrow {
  <!-- background: url('http://is200.imagesocket.com/images/2014/10/29/2716483-0cvp.png') no-repeat 1px 1px;
  -->padding-left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.steps {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.green {
  background: #7dba00 !important;
  color: #666666 !important;
}

.grey {
  color: #666666 !important;
}

.open .green:after {
  border-left-color: #7dba00 !important;
}

.wrap .num.last:after {
  display: none
}

.wrap .num.last:before {
  display: none
}

.black {
  background: #000 !important;
  color: #fff!important;
}

.open .black:after {
  border-left-color: #000 !important;
  color: #fff!important;
}

.steps li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.wrap {
  float: left;
}

.num {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #7dba00;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 4px 0 0;
}

.num b,
.steps p span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
}

.num:after {
  content: " ";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 14px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 14px solid #fff;
  border-left: 14px solid #7dba00;
  position: absolute;
  right: -4px;
  top: 1px;
}

.steps p {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 14px;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 10em;
  padding: 0 10px 0 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.closed .num:after {
  border-left-color: #000
}

.closed .num {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000
}

.closed .num.last:after {
  display: none
}

.open .num:after {
  border-left-color: #ccc;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  z-index: 1;
}

.open .num:before {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 15px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #fff;
  border-left: 15px solid #7dba00;
  position: absolute;
  right: -5px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.open .num {
  background: #ccc;
}

.open .wrap {
  border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px;
  border: 1px solid #7dba00;
}

li.open:after {
  content: " ";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 16px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 16px solid #fff;
  border-left: 15px solid #7dba00;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

li.open:before {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  content: " ";
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 14px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1px;
  top: 1px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.expanded {
  display: none;
  <!--bbackground-color: red;
  -->padding-right: 900px;
}

.tab {
  <!--background-color: yellow;
  --><!--border: 2px solid black;
  -->border-collapse: collapse;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: 230px;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.completed span {
  background-color: NONE;
  color: #95db89;
  border: 2px solid #95db89;
}

.todo span {
  background-color: none;
  color: #E1E6EB;
  border: 2px solid #E1E6EB;
}

.list span {
  color: #58D68D;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.breadcrumb-pagination div p {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 30px auto 25px;
}

.active p {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #00abc9;
  padding-bottom: 27px;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
  color: #3c4043;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.completed p {
  color: #bsb7c1;
}

.list p {
  color: #3c4043;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.completed span::before {
  content: '\2713'
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 365px;
  color: #444;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 98%;
}

th {
  background: linear-gradient(#000000, #4d4d4d);
  border-left: 1px solid #555;
  border-right: 1px solid #777;
  border-top: 1px solid #555;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #999;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}

th:after {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, .08));
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 15%;
  left: 0;
  margin: 1px 0 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
}

th:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #777;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 #999;
}

th:last-child {
  box-shadow: inset -1px 1px 0 #999;
}

td {
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  padding: 8px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 300ms;
}

td:first-child {
  box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 #fff;
}

td:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 #fff;
}

tr {
  background: url(https://jackrugile.com/images/misc/noise-diagonal.png);
}

tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background: #f1f1f1 url(https://jackrugile.com/images/misc/noise-diagonal.png);
}

tr:last-of-type td {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 #fff;
}

tr:last-of-type td:first-child {
  box-shadow: inset 1px -1px 0 #fff;
}

tr:last-of-type td:last-child {
  box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 0 #fff;
}

h1 {
  color: #444;
  text-shadow: 1px 0px 1px #ccc, 0px 1px 1px #eee, 2px 1px 1px #ccc, 1px 2px 1px #eee, 3px 2px 1px #ccc, 2px 3px 1px #eee, 4px 3px 1px #ccc, 3px 4px 1px #eee, 5px 4px 1px #ccc, 4px 5px 1px #eee, 6px 5px 1px #ccc, 5px 6px 1px #eee, 7px 6px 1px #ccc;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.tab {
  text-align: center;
}

.tab .nav-tabs {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.tab .nav-tabs li {
  margin: 0;
}

.tab .nav-tabs li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 80px 25px 0 25px;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #999;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  margin-right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.tab .nav-tabs li a span {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #999;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.tab .nav-tabs li.active a span {
  background: #29335c;
  color: #fff;
}

.tab .nav-tabs li a span i {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.tab .nav-tabs li.active a,
.tab .nav-tabs li a:hover {
  color: black;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

.tab .nav-tabs li.active a {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #29335c;
}

.tab .tab-content {
  padding: 30px 0 0 19px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
  line-height: 26px;
  text-align: left;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  width: 600px;
}

.tab .tab-content .tab-pane #Section3_table {
  margin-left: -8px;
}

.tab .tab-content h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .tab .nav-tabs li {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .tab .nav-tabs li:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>

<body>
  <title> Order Tracking System </title>
  <center>
    <h1> ORDER TRACKING SYSTEM </h1>
    <br>
    <table class="bts_table">
      <tr>
        <th>ORDER NUMBER</th>
        <th>CUSTOMER NAME</th>
        <th>LOCATION</th>
      </tr>

      <form action="save.php" method="POST">
        <td valign="top"><span class="closedArrow"> 12345 </span></td>
        <td valign="top"><span class="closedArrow"> JOHN </span></td>
        <td valign="top" class="collapsed">
          <ol class="steps">
            <li>
              <div class="num green"><b>1</b></div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="num green"><b>2</b></div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="num green"><b>3</b></div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="num green"><b>4</b></div>
            </li>
            <li class="open">
              <div class="wrap">
                <div class="num grey"><b>5</b></div>
                <p><span>SHIPPING</span><span>IN PROGRESS</span></p>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="closed">
              <div class="num"><b>6</b></div>
            </li>
            <li class="closed">
              <div class="num"><b>7</b></div>
            </li>
            <li class="closed">
              <div class="num"><b>8</b></div>
            </li>
            <li class="closed">
              <div class="num"><b>9</b></div>
            </li>
            <li class="closed">
              <div class="num last"><b>10</b></div>
            </li>

          </ol>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" class="expanded">
          <ol class="steps">
            <li class="open">
              <div class="wrap">
                <div class="num green"><b>1</b></div>
                <p><span>ORDER</span><span>Done: 03/18/2019</span></p>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="open">
              <div class="wrap">
                <div class="num green"><b>2</b></div>
                <p><span>PACKING</span><span>Done: 03/18/2019</span></p>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="open">
              <div class="wrap">
                <div class="num green"><b>3</b></div>
                <p><span>CHECKING</span><span>Done: 03/18/2019</span></p>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="open">
              <div class="wrap">
                <div class="num green"><b>4</b></div>
                <p><span>RECHECKING</span><span>Done: 03/18/2019</span></p>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="open">
              <div class="wrap">
                <div class="num grey"><b>5</b></div>
                <p><span>SHIPPING</span><span>ONGOING</span></p>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="open">
              <div class="wrap">
                <div class="num black"><b>6</b></div>
                <p><span>COURIER</span><span>NOT YET DONE </span></p>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="open">
              <div class="wrap">
                <div class="num black"><b>7</b></div>
                <p><span>DELIVERY</span><span>NOT YET DONE </span></p>
              </div>

              <li class="open">
                <div class="wrap">
                  <div class="num black last"><b>10</b></div>
                  <p><span>CUSTOMER</span><span>NOT YET DONE </span></p>
                </div>
              </li>
          </ol>
          <hr>
          <div class="tableDiv">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="tab" role="tabpanel">
                    <center>
                      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" style="width: 800px">
                        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#Section1" aria-controls="build_details" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span><i class="fa fa-cog" style="font-size:35px; padding: 8px 9px 9px 11px;"></i></span> Order Details</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#Section2" aria-controls="logistics" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span><i class="fa fa-bar-chart" style="font-size:25px; padding: 12px 9px 9px 10px;"></i></span> Logistics</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#Section3" aria-controls="reports" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span><i class="fa fa-file-text" style="font-size:26px; padding: 14px 9px 9px 13px;"></i></span> Reports</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#Section4" aria-controls="shipments" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" style="font-size:34px; padding: 10px 9px 9px 11px;"></i></span> Shipments</a></li>
                      </ul>


                      <div class="tab-content tabs">
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="Section1">
                          <table border="2px">
                            <tr>
                              <th>ITEM</th>
                              <th>DETAILS</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>Bag</td>
                              <td>1pc; Green</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>Pouch</td>
                              <td>1pc; Blue</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>Necklace</td>
                              <td>1pc; Heart shape; Gold</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>Shoes</td>
                              <td>1 pair; Red; Size 6</td>
                            </tr>
                          </table><br>
                          <hr>
                        </div>


                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="Section2">
                          <table border="2px">
                            <tr>
                              <th>CUSTOMER</th>
                              </th>
                              <th>DETAILS</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>NAME</td>
                              <td>John Smith</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>SHIPPING ADDRESS</td>
                              <td> 445 Mount Eden Road, Mount Eden, Auckland. Rural </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>TELEPHONE NUMBER</td>
                              <td>754-3010</td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </div>


                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="Section3">
                          <center><a class="btn btn-danger" href="add_report.php">ADD REPORT</a><br><br>
                            <table id="Section3_table" name="Section3">
                              <tr>
                                <th>ISSUE</th>
                                <th>DETAILS</th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                              </tr>
                          </center>
                          </table><br>
                          <hr>
                        </div>


                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="Section4">
                          <table border="2px">
                            <tr>
                              <th>COURIER NAME</th>
                              <th>DATE SHIPPED</th>
                              <th>DATE ARRIVED</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td></td>
                              <td></td>
                              <td></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table><br>
                          <hr>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top"><span class="closedArrow"> 67890 </span></td>
            <td valign="top"><span class="closedArrow"> JANE </span></td>
            <td valign="top" class="collapsed">
              <ol class="steps">
                <li class="open">
                  <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="num grey"><b>1</b></div>
                    <p><span>PACKING</span><span>IN PROGRESS</span></p>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="closed">
                  <div class="num"><b>2</b></div>
                </li>
                <li class="closed">
                  <div class="num"><b>3</b></div>
                </li>
                <li class="closed">
                  <div class="num"><b>4</b></div>
                </li>
                <li class="closed">
                  <div class="num"><b>5</b></div>
                </li>
                <li class="closed">
                  <div class="num"><b>6</b></div>
                </li>
                <li class="closed">
                  <div class="num"><b>7</b></div>
                </li>
                <li class="closed">
                  <div class="num"><b>8</b></div>
                </li>
                <li class="closed">
                  <div class="num"><b>9</b></div>
                </li>
                <li class="closed">
                  <div class="num last"><b>10</b></div>
                </li>

              </ol>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" class="expanded">
              <ol class="steps">
                <li class="open">
                  <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="num green"><b>1</b></div>
                    <p><span>ORDER</span><span>ONGOING</span></p>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="open">
                  <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="num black"><b>2</b></div>
                    <p><span>PACKING</span><span>NOT YET DONE</span></p>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="open">
                  <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="num black"><b>3</b></div>
                    <p><span>CHECKING</span><span>NOT YET DONE</span></p>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="open">
                  <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="num black"><b>4</b></div>
                    <p><span>RECHECKING</span><span>NOT YET DONE</span></p>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="open">
                  <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="num black"><b>5</b></div>
                    <p><span>SHIPPING</span><span>NOT YET DONE</span></p>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="open">
                  <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="num black"><b>6</b></div>
                    <p><span>COURIER</span><span>NOT YET DONE</span></p>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="open">
                  <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="num black"><b>7</b></div>
                    <p><span>DELIVERY</span><span>NOT YET DONE</span></p>
                  </div>

                  <li class="open">
                    <div class="wrap">
                      <div class="num black last"><b>10</b></div>
                      <p><span>CUSTOMER</span><span>NOT YET DONE</span></p>
                    </div>
                  </li>
              </ol>
              <hr>


              <div class="tableDiv">

                <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="tab" role="tabpanel">
                        <center>
                          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" style="width: 800px">
                            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#Section5" aria-controls="build_details" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span><i class="fa fa-cog" style="font-size:35px; padding: 8px 9px 9px 11px;"></i></span> Order Details</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#Section6" aria-controls="logistics" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span><i class="fa fa-bar-chart" style="font-size:25px; padding: 12px 9px 9px 10px;"></i></span> Logistics</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#Section7" aria-controls="reports" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span><i class="fa fa-file-text" style="font-size:26px; padding: 14px 9px 9px 13px;"></i></span> Reports</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#Section8" aria-controls="shipments" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" style="font-size:34px; padding: 10px 9px 9px 11px;"></i></span> Shipments</a></li>
                          </ul>


                          <div class="tab-content tabs">
                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="Section5">
                              <table border="2px">
                                <tr>
                                  <th>ITEM</th>
                                  <th>DETAILS</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>Dress</td>
                                  <td>1pc; Yellow</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>Hat</td>
                                  <td>1pc; Green</td>
                                </tr>
                              </table><br>
                              <hr>
                            </div>


                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="Section6">
                              <table border="2px">
                                <tr>
                                  <th>CUSTOMER</th>
                                  </th>
                                  <th>DETAILS</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>NAME</td>
                                  <td>Jane Doe</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>SHIPPING ADDRESS</td>
                                  <td>21 Greens Road RD 2 Ruawai 0592. Partial addresses: Main Highway </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>TELEPHONE NUMBER</td>
                                  <td>1-541-754-3010</td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                            </div>


                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="Section7">
                              <center><a class="btn btn-danger" href="add_report.php">ADD REPORT</a><br><br>
                                <table id="Section3_table" name="Section3">
                                  <tr>
                                    <th>ISSUE</th>
                                    <th>DETAILS</th>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                  </tr>
                              </center>
                              </table><br>
                              <hr>
                            </div>


                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="Section8">
                              <table border="2px">
                                <tr>
                                  <th>COURIER NAME</th>
                                  <th>DATE SHIPPED</th>
                                  <th>DATE ARRIVED</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td></td>
                                  <td></td>
                                  <td></td>
                                </tr>
                              </table><br>
                              <hr>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Congratulations, you've earned the **[VoteUp privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)** consider to use it if any answer helps you if any answer is what you're looking for Mark it as the **[correct answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** For the future readers.